# $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty {a_n}$ converges $\iff \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty {a_{n_k}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $({a_n})_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ a sequence,and let $({a_{n_k}})_{k\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ the sequence of all terms of $({a_n})$ different than zero. Then $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty {a_n}\text{ converges} \iff \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty {a_{n_k}} \text{ converges}$$

My approach to the proof:

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty {a_n}$ converges, so for every $\epsilon>0$ ,$\exists N\in{\mathbb{N}} $ so that $\forall n,m\ge N$ then $|{a_m}-{a_n}|<\epsilon$. 
Let $B=[j\in{\mathbb{N}}|{a_j}=0]$, so that  ${a_n}={a_j}\cup {a_i}$. Can I express $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty {a_n}$ as $\sum_\limits{n\notin B}^\infty {a_n} +\sum_\limits{n\in B}^\infty {a_n}$

I need some help proving this, it might be trivial  but I'm having problems with notation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Surely, when you sum terms of the **sub**sequence $a_{n_k}$, your indexing variable must be $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the partial sums

$$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i
$$

For any given $\varepsilon$, let $N$ be that integer such that for all $p, q \geq N, |S_p-S_q| < \varepsilon$.  Either there exists a minimum $K$ such that $n_K \geq N$ (and then for all $r, s \geq K, |S_{n_r}-S_{n_s}| < \varepsilon$ and the second series is convergent), or else there does not exist such a minimum $K$, in which case the second series has a finite number of terms and is convergent.

ETA: Oh yes, the inverse.  For any given $\varepsilon$, let $K$ be that integer such that for all $r, s \geq K, |S_{n_r}-S_{n_s}| < \varepsilon$.  We observe that for any $n$, $S_n = S_{n_r}$ where $r = \max_{n_s \leq n} s$ (since we are only adding a finite number of trailing zeros).  Let $N = n_K$.  Then for any $p, q \geq N, |S_p-S_q| = |S_{n_r}-S_{n_s}| < \varepsilon$ for some $r, s \geq K$, and the first series is convergent.

Comment: Could you explain me the case when there's not a minimum K?(for the first part of the proof)

Comment: Sure.  Let's be concrete and suppose $N = 100$ for a given $\varepsilon$.  If there isn't a $K$ such that $n_K \geq N$, that means that there are no non-zero terms in the original series beyond $N = 100$, so $\{a_{n_k}\}$ has at most $100$ terms, and the series must therefore converge.  I should say, incidentally, that if there *is* such a $K$, there must be a minimum such $K$, by the well-ordering of the natural numbers.

Comment: And what is $\max_{n_s \leq n} s$ ?

Comment: That's the maximum value of $s$ such that $n_s \leq n$.  Heuristically, it's the index to the last non-zero element that comes at or before $a_n$.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would try to prove your equivalence by thinking about the definition of infinite series. That is, by definition, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \lim_{N\to\infty} S_N$$

where $S_N$ is the partial sum of the first $N$ elements in the sequence,

$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$$

Then, the first sum is the limit of the sequence $S_1,S_2,S_3\dots$, and, because of the definition of the subsequence $n_k$, the second sum is the limit of a *subsequence* of $S_1,S_2,\dots$ **with all repetitions removed**. (*note: this statement needs a formal proof that is not hard*).

Now, you only need to prove that removing all repetitions from a sequence does not change it's convergence, a much simpler task. If $b_n$ is a sequence, and $b_{n_k}$ is a sub-sequence of $b_n$ without repetitions, then:

- Say $b_n$ converges. Then $b_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $b_n$ and it converges.
- Say $b_{n_k}$ converges to $b$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a value $K$ such that if $k>K$, $|b_{n_k}-b|<\epsilon$. Set $N = n_K$. Then, for all $n>N$, you have $b_n = b_{n_k}$ for some $k>K$ (*why*?), and thus $|b_n-b| < \epsilon$, and convergence is shown.

Comment: Neat.  I like this approach.